# Is IEEE802.11 preamble a null frame?

Tags: 802.1

I'd like to know if preamble is a null frame. One person has quoted such in [this forum](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,16698292). But, in many other websites, it is given that it is some part of information needed to receive and transfer data. Could you kindly clarify me?

Comment: Out of interest... Why?

Comment: @TomO'Connor I have to understand the frame format, as a part of my WLAN training. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a quick glance at the [802.11-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf) specification from the IEEE..

There's a few sections in that document referring to generating either a long or short preamble, and in no case is it null data.

> Figure 17-1 shows the format for the interoperable (long) PPDU,
> including the High Rate PLCP preamble, the High Rate PLCP header, and
> the PSDU. The PLCP preamble contains the following fields: SYNC and
> SFD.
>
> The PLCP header contains the following fields: signaling
> (SIGNAL), service (SERVICE), length (LENGTH), and CRC-16. Each of
> these fields is described in detail in 17.2.3. The format for the
> PPDU, including the long High Rate PLCP preamble, the long High Rate
> PLCP header, and the PSDU, does not differ from the format for 1 Mb/s
> and 2 Mb/s.
>
> The only exceptions are: a) The encoding of the rate in
> the SIGNAL field; b) The use of a bit in the SERVICE field to resolve
> an ambiguity in PSDU length in octets, when the length is expressed in
> whole microseconds; c) The use of a bit in the SERVICE field to
> indicate if the optional PBCC mode is being used; d) The use of a bit
> in the SERVICE field to indicate that the transit frequency and bit
> clocks are locked.

So it looks very much like the preamble contains various bits of data about the PHY properties of the signal.

I doubt it's null, in any case.

[image: preamble diagram]

The image shows that the preamble is comprised of the Sync (56 0s), ***And*** the SFD (Start Frame Delimiter), which is a [16 bit field](http://www.cwins.wpi.edu/publications/pown/chapter_11.pdf), comprised of `0000110010111101` for a long preamble, and `1001` for a short preamble.

Have a read of the 802.11 standard, and this: http://www.cwins.wpi.edu/publications/pown/chapter_11.pdf page 453.

Comment: I'd want you to consult with [this link](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/24444-802pt1?start=4) also. In the diagram, it is mentioned as `scrambled 0`s. Thanks.